# Facebook SDK publish_actions permission and Shared dialog

Tags: facebook

We use standard Share dialog in our iOS application. After sharing I need to get post_id to check the publication in the future.  But post_id can be returned only if we have public_action permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). But when I'm trying to submit review for publish_actions, I must confirm that I *do not* use standard Share dialog. So, to get result of Share dialog I cannot use Share dialog. Are there any solutions of this problem?

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: what for do yo need to know the publication exactly?

Comment: After 48 hours I have to know if the publication still exists and not private

Comment: ok, but what for exactly? please be more specific, that´s a very important question.

Comment: Because we pay money for users who share selfie using our application.

Comment: ok, that is why i asked. your use case is not allowed according to the platform policy. you MUST read the platform policy before creating any app. you are not allowed to reward users in any way for sharing. you would never get publish_actions approved for that anyway.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Sorry, are you sure you are correct? I've just checked the policy - there is no direct forbidden. There is another term: "Don't charge for most of the content in your app. Ensure your app contains free shareable content. ". Could you please give me more specific place in Policy ? Thank you in advance, Serge

Comment: i am 100% sure i am correct, it is a fact. "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions."

Comment: this has been discussed plenty of times on stackoverflow and in the official facebook dev group on facebook too. rewarding users for sharing something is 100% forbidden for good reasons > it prevents the users friends from all the spam.

Comment: "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions" - this is exactly what we do. Log in and check in. No other actions.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read those discussions. Our application was already approved by Facebook team (with standard permissions). And there is no direct prohibition in the Policy.

Comment: you also want to incentivize "other actions": you incentivize users to share something, so they get a reward. sharing must not be rewarded, period.

Comment: there is a direct prohibition. ask a lawyer, or a facebook developer ;) - you will not get publish_actions for this, because it´s not allowed. and you NEED publish_actions, so...

Comment: feel free to ask here, lots of facebook employees in there, they will tell you the same: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: But why the Facebook SDK includes Share dialog if it is prohibitted? :)

Comment: sharing is allowed. rewarding users for sharing is not. users need to share something because they want to, NOT because they got rewarded.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. Thank you!